# why struts2 package are maintained separated?

Tags: struts2

Is there any reason they are maintained separate packages folder structure for struts core api & com.opensymphony.xwork2 in struts2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, but it's not a technical issue.

Longer answer: Because XWork 2 is a completely separate project upon which WebWork, then Struts 2, was built. The project "acquired" XW2 but it remains a separate entity for the time being. Its current location is better than it was, too.

We've talked about folding it in and bringing it into the "Struts family", but it's important that it remain a separate entity, because it is not directly related to the web layer. Some people, myself included, have used XW2 on its own for its command pattern implementation.

If we re-brand it as a Struts component, it will likely remain as an individual component, although I'm not quite sure what it will look like at this point, where it will live, etc. I'm personally not in favor of a complete merge precisely because XW2 is not web-related, is used outside of web apps, and is a logically-separate component.